# sqlite3 cannot open database file, running Centos, flask uwsgi nginx

Tags: nginx, sqlite, flask, centos, uwsgi

I have a fairly simple flask app which runs fine on my local machine.  The app uses sqlite3.  I am trying to deploy to a CentOS machine running nginx and uwsgi.  The app starts but when I try to access the site through chrome, it raises an exception:

sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file

I believe I have all the permissions correct, the user starting the app has ownership of the database file.  All the directories have 777 permissions.  The database has 665 permissions.  nginx is started using sudo.

I have combed through all the existing posts about this kind of thing.  People talk about permissions, but I am pretty sure I have those correct.  The name of the file is correct.

DATABASE = 'sqlite:////home/.../firstDB.db'

I get the same error if the database points to a nonexistent file.  What else could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the file name prefix of sqlite/// is incorrect.  I don't understand this, as it worked before.  I just put the file name only and it works now.